# Convert <requests.models.Response> into object

Tags: python, iterator, response, httpresponse

I sent a request and received a response as seen below. The python type(response) equals `requests.models.Response`.

The code below will save the object to a html file, but I want to convert it into the BeautifulSoup python object (var: html_file) without saving it into a local file. How do I do that? Thank you.

```
   response = requests.get(...)
   with open(local_filename, 'wb') as f:
     for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=1024):
       if chunk:
         f.write(chunk)
         f.flush()

   html_file = BeautifulSoup(open(html_file_dir), "html.parser")
```

Comment: Do you want to read the HTML page as string? Then you could do `html_string = response.text`

Comment: What is a "usable Python object"? Usable as what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `.text` property of the response to read data as string. Example how to read `https://www.google.com` without writing to file:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.google.com'

response = requests.get(url)

html_file = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

print(html_file.prettify())
```

**Further reading:**

[Developer interface to Requests](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/api/)